# Convert Column from String to Int - Alter Script MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Can you change a column from a varchar to an int.

I have a table with a zipcode column and I want the zips to be ints instead of varchars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ALTER COLUMN ZipCode INT
```

Comment: It just auto parses?  What happens on failure?  Like if one of my zipcodes is 'sadf'?

Comment: right, if there are any issues this will not run, but if they're all convertible to int, then it will

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I suggest you do NOT make that change at all.  You are in a better position for future growth if you can support the alphanumeric ZIPs outside of the US, and to do that your ZIP code column should remain a varchar.

For instance, just 2 minutes ago, I received an order from:

```
Hever, Belgium
VLA3191
```

Comment: I tend to agree, but there is a way to do it

Comment: What I need to do is find zips that are close when they don't exist in my DB. For instance 73070 is NOT in my db so when a use puts it in, I need to default their lat long to 73071 instead of throwing an error. So I need to be able to sort efficiently and compare one to another.

Comment: Took your advice - I was sort of forced to as I have non-numeric values in the db already...Worked around it by searching the text.  Not sure how efficient this is, but its not causing performance issues at the moment...

Comment: You did the right thing.  Another issue is that your client would have had to pad zeroes on some zip codes (I grew up in zip code 05452).  Defaulting to a close "string" zip should work just as well as defaulting to a close "int" zip, anyway.

Comment: You accepted my answer in the real world, and accepted Hunter's answer here?  wtf.

Comment: I accepted the answer that answered the question and took your advice.  Note, however, that I didn't take your advice because of your post - it was out of necessity.  Thanks for the down-vote.

Comment: Also note: Your 'answer' is not an answer.